# String to float in OCaml: over and under approximation

Tags: ocaml, rounding-error

Given a string of a (possibly big) integer, I need to convert it to floating-point numbers, in OCaml. The problem is that the conversion is not always exact due to rounding errors. For example, `float_of_string "61035156250000000000"` would return `61035156249999998976`. How can I under-approximate and over-approximate the number to get an interval `[a, b]` where

1. `a` is the largest representable floating-point number such that `a <= 61035156250000000000`
2. `b` is the smallest representable floating-point number such that `b >= 61035156250000000000`?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. Previous answers to similar questions here on SO often cite this paper by Gay: [Correctly Rounded Binary-Decimal and Decimal-Binary Conversions](http://www.ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You have to get an approximate value, bracket the accurate value (which may not be representable as float) and binary search. Here is a short program I wrote to do this:

```
let num_of_float x =
   let two = Num.num_of_int 2 in
   let rec expand x =
      let fr, wh = modf x in
      Num.add_num (Num.num_of_int (int_of_float wh))
      (if fr = 0.0 then Num.num_of_int 0 else
      Num.div_num (expand (2.0*.fr)) two) in
   let fl, ex = frexp x in
   if ex <> 0 then Num.mult_num (expand fl) (Num.power_num two (Num.num_of_int ex))
   else
      expand x

let bracket str =
   let x = Num.num_of_string str in
   let rec binsearch a b =
      let t = (b-.a)*.0.5 +. a in
      if (t = a) || (t = b) then (a,b) else
      match Num.compare_num x (num_of_float t) with
        | -1 -> binsearch a t
        | 0 -> (t,t)
        | 1 -> binsearch t b
        | _ -> failwith "compare_num" in
   let near = Num.float_of_num x in
   let delta = 1.0 +. (4.0*.epsilon_float) in
      binsearch (near/.delta) (near*.delta)

let () =
   let l,r = bracket "61035156250000000000" in
   Printf.printf "[%.16g = %s, %.16g = %s]\n"
    l (Num.string_of_num (num_of_float l)) r (Num.string_of_num (num_of_float r))
```

Compile with the Num module to get this output:

```
[6.103515625e+19 = 61035156249999998976, 6.103515625000001e+19 = 61035156250000007168]
```

You will need to tweak the delta value and check for NaNs, infinity and conversion errors to get a robust method.

Comment: `int_of_float wh` cannot handle the case when `wh` is outside representable range of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This has to due with the fact that float numbers are stored as A_ * pow(2,B_).

What you need is a BigInt
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Big_int.html

Comment: Big_int can represent such big numbers; but in my application, one library requires intervals of floating-points to work.

Comment: I recommend for your use case, keep a big_int mantissa and power of 10 exponent, then convert to float when needed.